# Python Numba @jit produces error when working with Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I am trying to use Numba with Numpy arrays to test the possible speed up of this tool. When I run the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/Python

import numpy as np
from numba import jit

SIZE = 1000
array1 = np.full((SIZE, SIZE), 0)
array2 = np.full((SIZE, SIZE), 0)

@jit(nopython = True)
def fun():

    #SIZE = 1000
    #array1 = np.full((SIZE, SIZE), 0)
    #array2 = np.full((SIZE, SIZE), 0)

    for i in np.arange(0, 1000):
        print(i)

        for j in np.arange(0, 1000):
            array1[i,j] = i+j
            array2[i,j] = i-j
            array1[i,j] = array2[j,i]

            for k in np.arange(0, 1000):
                array1[i,j] = i+j
                array2[i,j] = i-j
                array1[i,j] = array2[j,i]

                for l in np.arange(0, 1000):
                    array1[i,j] = i+j
                    array2[i,j] = i-j
                    array1[i,j] = array2[j,i]

print(fun())
```

I get the following error (not the entire error message is shown):

```
    raise value
numba.errors.InternalError: Cannot modify value of type readonly array(int64, 2d, C)
[1] During: typing of setitem at Python_array_prog.py (21)
--%<----------------------------------------------------------------------------


File "Python_array_prog.py", line 21:
def fun():
    <source elided>
        for j in np.arange(0, 1000):
            array1[i,j] = i+j
            ^

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

To see Python/NumPy features supported by the latest release of Numba visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html
and
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

For more information about typing errors and how to debug them visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile

If you think your code should work with Numba, please report the error message
and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer at:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new
```

It seems that the compiler is confused by the array indices or the array itself.
Thank You in advance for any help :)

Kind Regards,
Qba Liu

Comment: you need to pass the arrays as arguments to the function ```def fun(array1, array2):``` and then ```print(fun(array1, array2))```

Comment: Please consider using `range` instead of `np.arange`. The later create a new Numpy array with a probably significant overhead while the former has a zero overhead. Note that modifying globals is a really bad idea in term of software engineering besides being the issue here for Numba.

Comment: Thans Nin17 and Jerome Richard. I have implemented both your suggestions and it worked :)

Comment: `array1` and `array2` can't be modified because they are fixed at compile time. If you don't modify them in the Numba code, but modify them outside of your numba function you can get wrong results without an error message which is even worse. As a default, always pass variables and arrays to the Numba function, apart from some special cases where you explicitly want to compile them into your code.